# Who has the responsibility to handle CORS?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, graphql, cors, client-server

I'm developing a GraphQL API on Laravel for mobile and web applications. One of the frontend developer asking me to disable CORS on the server side because he cannot work with the API due to CORS problem. The Vue application on his localhost is making requests to my Test API which is on a URL.

From what I understand this isn't problem for the server side, CORS is s security measure for the server. I believe for development Vue developer need to handle this problem with adding a proxy to his localhost.

Comment: This is first and foremost a people problem. If the frontend devs can't get things done, your API work is pointless; you are a team collaborating to deliver value, act like it. Yes one solution is to proxy locally, but is that the best for your context? Maybe the dev server should allow localhost so you can be more confident that the system works together properly (you can't use a dev proxy for the production frontend)?

Comment: put yourself in his place/position, just try to use own api from your localhost (or any client app hosted on any other, different IP) project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are both responsible to get the application done and pointing fingers at one another does not solve this problem. This is not a technical problem.

Adding a proxy to the frontend development environment is one way to solve this problem. Another way is to whitelist the domain they are working on, or even putting a wildcard in there as the frontend developer suggested. CORS is a security feature, but it is meaningless for a development environment that does not contain any production data. Being able to get a development environment up and running without jumping through a lot of hoops helps productivity.

**Work together. Your responsibility is to create an application, and without a frontend you are also failing at your task of delivering that application.**